# Is it bad to instantiate request and response objects in other functions?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, backend, dao

I could not find a similar question, and this could be a dumb question, not sure, I couldn't figure out what keywords to search for.

For example, we have some sort of request/response pair for accessing information from the database (forgive me, using VB .NET at work, not my choice, so I'm just staying consistent)

```
Public Class ItemAddRequest
    Public param1 As String = ""
    Public param2 As String = ""
End Class

Public Class ItemAddResponse
    Public returnParameter As MyItemObject = ""

    Public Function Invoke(req As ItemAddRequst)
        ' SQL Queries go here
        ' Build my returnParameter
    End Function
End Class
```

So these are used for the front end to get information to display on the front end, but is it bad to use these somewhere else in your code for the sole purpose of getting that info or adding that info? Generally you would want to modularize (invented word) that and use methods of my MyItemObject to do this, but we already have a large collection of things that would need to be changed so we are not doing that, at least for now. So for example we are doing something like this

```
Public Class ParentItemAddRequest
    Public param1 As String = ""
    Public param2 As String = ""
End Class

Public Class ParentItemAddResponse
    Public returnParameter As MyParentItemObject = ""

    Public Function Invoke(req As ParentItemAddRequest)
        ' SQL Query goes here to add parent
        ' Now also need to add a regular MyItemObject
        Dim itemReq as new ItemAddRequest()
        Dim itemResp as new ItemAddResponse()
        itemReq.param1 = 'whatever
        itemReq.param2 = 'whatever

        itemResp.Invoke(itemReq)

        me.returnParameter = itemResp.returnParameter

    End Function
End Class
```

Doing this seems to work fine, but what kind of problems could we anticpate to cause? Or is this a completely normal thing? Seems odd to us. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If this code works than not much is wrong. If it aint broke then dont fix it. That being said, the only thing wrong with this code, i think, is that it uses wrong patterns. It just looks wrong. The only problem it would create is that it would confuse the hell out of new hires. Another serious implication of working this way is that the Class is now responsible for two things (1) declaring the data contract (2) defining the algo to fill it. This mixup is frowned upon according to SOLID principles. The mixup of responsibilities make it difficult to do unit testing and impact analysis.

When I find a `Request` class and `Response` class, the immediate assumption is that you guys are using the DTO pattern. The classes are assumed to be data contracts because of their naming convention. Now, the dtos are supposed to be simple POCOs devoid of any business logic. This is so that you can put all such classes in a seperate dll and different clients can use the shared data structures. So I wont be expecting the `Invoke` method there. I would expect that the dto is `filled` at the DAL layer either by handcrafted sqls in a `DAO` class or via some orm like entity framework.

With handcrafted sqls, I would expect a set of classes like `Class ParentItemDAO` with methods like `Function Add(req As AddParentItemRequest) As AddParentItemResponse`. Similarly I would expect a method `Function GetParentItemById` returning either a business object or a dto.

Comment: I am relatively new to web services (I'm a junior in university working on a co-op) and especially new to .NET (used Spring MVC at my previous internship), so some of my description is certainly going to be unclear because what I'm writing is based off of the large project that already exists. Thank you for your answer!